# Change external shape color in XML

Tags: android, xml, drawable

So, if I have a `shape`:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners 
        android:radius="10dp"/>

</shape>
```

And I want to have that shape in a `selector`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/someDrawable" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/someOtherDrawable" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/someOtherOTHERDrawable"/>

</selector>
```

How could I use my shape in my selector AND set the color of it? Is that even possible in to do in the XML? Would I have to use an `<include />` tag like this:

```
<item >
    <include layout="@drawable/myShape"
        android:color="#987" />
</item>
```

Comment: @Luksprog Following your format...... That's why I said "Is that even possible to do in the XML"......

Comment: @Luksprog I only asked, since it's possible to do programmatically with Java.

Comment: You can't because the xml drawables are not the place for such conditional logic. Their are static.

Comment: @Luksprog Okay. So, to have multiple fairly complex `shape`s with the only difference being the color, I would have to either write them all out or change the color in the Java code, right?

Comment: Yes, programatically setting the color is the solution.